# How to install Python Packages in Lambda Layer?

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda

I've been trying to build a small Post API gateway with Lambda. It need other Packages dependencies like *xlsxwriter* ...So I created a Zip File with the Packages inside and create Layer then just add and use it with the Lambda but I've always got this error: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'xlsxwriter'",
Can someone help me the way out?
Many thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you placed your dependencies like 'xlsxwriter' inside 'python' folder? For example ZIP file 'xlsxwriter.zip' should contain folder structure 'python/xlsxwriter' and upload that zip file. Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#awsui-tabs-0-python-panel:~:text=Example%20file%20structure%20for%20the%20Pillow%20library

Comment: Yes bro, as the pic above. I already had this package inside. I created Python Dir and use this command *pip3 install xlsxwriter  -t . * to install the package inside the Python Dir and then zip it for Layer

Comment: Are you using command line? I did it by just uploading zip file and created layer and added it into lambda function.

Comment: If you fine then we can connect and check.

Comment: No bro, I only used 1 command line above to install the Package into a Folder. Then I zip it and upload to create Layer. No idea why It did not work. The weird part is, If I tried to tests with Requests package, It worked but not work with this xlsxwriter

Comment: @Tringuyenminh did you found any solution for this?

Comment: this xlsxwriter package has C or C ++ in core which is not support for Lambda to install like this way. That's why it's not working bro. It's just my opinion